# Can the same set of private keys be used multiple times in a multisig wallet?

Tags: wallet, security, script, multi-signature

Is there any limitation to how many times the same set of private keys can exist within a multisig wallet? For example, could a 3 of 4 multisig wallet be created with two of the four keys being identical such that that key is always required to sign for a withdrawal along with one of the other two keys?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, nothing stops you from creating such a wallet. However, there are more efficient ways of encoding your desired policy than a 3-of-4 multisig with one key repeated twice.

If you use the [Miniscript](https://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/) policy compiler and input the policy `and(pk(A),or(pk(B),pk(C)))`, you get this script which doesn't repeat any of the keys:

```
<B> OP_CHECKSIG
OP_NOTIF
  <C> OP_CHECKSIGVERIFY
OP_ENDIF
<A> OP_CHECKSIG
```

Comment: I tried to create a multisig wallet using the suggested policy in Sparrow wallet but it threw an "invalid output descriptor" error. If I try to create a simple 2 of 4 multisig wallet, it generates the following descriptor:

wsh(sortedmulti(2,Keystore1,Keystore2,Keystore3,Keystore4))

This appears to be a different notation. What should the descriptor be in Sparrow wallet for a multisig wallet supporting (A and (B or C)) ? The Sparrow GUI doesn't seem to provide options to create more complex wallets such as this.

Comment: Hi Josh, if you have another question please use the Ask Question button.

Comment: I have posted this as a new question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/119309/create-a-multisig-wallet-using-sparrow-wallet-with-keys-a-and-b-or-c

Answer (score 0):

Try to test it in Bitcoin Core, better in Regtest:

- Create a 'blank' 'watching-only' 'descriptor' wallet.
- Get some public key(s) for testing as well as the corresponding WIF private keys.
- Create an sh or wsh MultiSig descriptor using multiple public keys, for example (two same pubKeys): sh(sortedmulti(3,pubKey_1,pubKey_1,pubKey_2,pubKey_3))
- Go to console and type the command getdescriptorinfo "YOUR_DESCRIPTOR" and take note of the "checksum" that you'll need to include to import the descriptor.
- Import it to your newly created wallet using the command: importdescriptors "[{"desc": "YOUR_DESCRIPTOR#checksum","label": "YOUR_LABEL","timestamp": "now"}]"
- The address should be included in your Receiving addresses with the specified label
- Now, do some tests.